# Persisting a network query and then checking whether another is needed with RxJava

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

This seems like it should be simple, but I'm struggling with the correct way of flowing the RxJava chain.

For instance, what isn't working is using `flatMap` to both persist data and check if another api query is needed:

```
return remote(amount = 2))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap {
            insertAll(it)
            // Return an Observable<Boolean>, true if another api query is needed
            shouldGetMore(it)
        }
        .flatMap {
            if (it) remote(amount = 3)
            // If another query is not needed just return an empty observable
            else Observable.just(listOf())
        }
        .flatMapCompletable { insertAll(it) /* If another query was needed insert the result here */  }
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

With the above, `insertAll()` isn't called the first time because the function `insetrtAll` is a completable and is therefore not subscribed to in the `flatMap`. Instead only `shouldGetMore()` is executed. Now, here is my question:

For this to work I would need a `flatMapCompletable` at the beginning like so:

```
return remote(amount = 2))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMapCompletable { insertAll(it) }
        // ...
```

But if I do this then I no longer have access to the results of the first api query to check if I `shouldGetMore`. My only thought is making `insertAll` not a `Completable` but rather an `Observable` that returns what was persisted after the fact, thus allowing me to complete the chain.

But this seems like an ugly approach, so I would be curious if anyone else had any other ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `insertAll(it).andThen(shouldGetMore(it))`.

Comment: @akarnokd Thank you! This worked perfectly, would you like to submit it as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Completable` offers the `andThen` operator to continue with any of the reactive base types:

```
return remote(amount = 2))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMap {
        insertAll(it)
        .andThen(shouldGetMore(it)) // <----------------------------------------
    }
    .flatMap {
        if (it) remote(amount = 3)
        else Observable.just(listOf())
    }
    .flatMapCompletable { insertAll(it) }
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```